# Lettuce Using RedisAsyncCommands with non String,String codec

Tags: java, redis, netty, lettuce

I want to initialize Lettuce's RedisAsyncCommands with (K, V) different from `<String, String>` which is the default initialization codec for Lettuce. I want `<String, byte[]>` , how can I do that?

```
RedisURI redisUri = RedisURI.builder().withHost(configuration.getTelematicsRedis().getHost()).withPort(configuration.getTelematicsRedis().getPort()).build();
RedisClient client = RedisClient.create(redisUri);
RedisAsyncCommands<String, String> redisAsyncCommands = client.connect().async();
```

I went through the lettuce documentation and some other resources online but it's still not clear to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We can do the same by passing the required Key and Value codec in this way:

```
RedisURI redisUri = RedisURI.builder().withHost(configuration.getTelematicsRedis().getHost()).withPort(configuration.getTelematicsRedis().getPort()).build();
RedisClient client = RedisClient.create(redisUri);
RedisAsyncCommands<String, byte[]> redisAsyncCommands = client.connect(RedisCodec.of(new StringCodec(), new ByteArrayCodec())).async();
```